# Can this query be simplified?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a simpler way to perform this query?

Actually using this in part of a larger query
Would rather not use EXCEPT, UNION, INTERSECT
As part of the more larger query the optimizer can get stupid on the derived table and except
Not of value to post the larger query as it is dynamic

The PK on docSVsys is sID
The PK on docMVenum1 is sID, enumID, valueID

```
  select sID from docSVsys 
 EXCEPT 
  select sID 
    from docMVenum1 
   where enumID = 140 
     and valueID in (1,2) 
   group by sID
  having count(*) = 2 


  select docSVsys.sID from docSVsys 
    left outer join 
         ( select sID 
             from docMVenum1 
            where enumID = 140 
              and valueID in (1,2) 
            group by sID
           having count(*) = 2 ) as joinTable 
      on docSVsys.sID = joinTable.sID
   where joinTable.sID is null
```

I know the two queries are the same
I am looking for a 3rd simpler

Answer (score 1):

I believe the IN operator might cause an inefficiency. Try this:

```
   select sID 
   from docSVsys 
 EXCEPT 
   select sID 
   from (
     select d1.sID
     from docMVenum1 d1
     join docMVenum1 d2
       on d1.sID  = d2.sID
     where d1.enumID = 140 and d1.valueID = 1
       and d2.enumID = 140 and d2.valueID = 2 
   ) T
```

Comment: I tried that.  If the main query has 5 or more except, union, or join then the query optimizer can get stupid.  Some times it gets stupid at 4.  And with except, union, intersect cannot even apply hints.

Comment: @Blam: SYBASE SQL Server used to exhibit that behaviour back in the mid-'90's as a consequence of how the optimizer processed only 4 tables at a time. The table-count for that behaviour should be much, much higher now.

Comment: @Blam: What is the measured performance of the query as I presented it?

Comment: @Blam: Also, an index (enumID, valueID,sID) on docMEenum1 will help this query considerably.

Comment: Well I am seeing that problem today with 2008-R2.  As I stated it is not about the individual query but how to simplify it as part of a bigger query.  The solution you proposed does not help the bigger query nor the individual query.  And as I stated I want to get away from except.  But still +1 as it was worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

do you absolutely need the aggregation? cant you just do the grouping and aggregation on the data as created tables, that would be a performance booster.

CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS         (select sID
             from docMVenum1 int
            where enumID = 140 
              and valueID in (1,2)

the only query you would then have to run is the below.

select * from new_table where count(*) = 2
            group by sID

Comment: That still aggregates and it is not faster.